# Having trouble getting vbscript to recognize an input area

Tags: vbscript, autofill

I'm very new to all this, but I'm trying to write a script to quickly fill out a form we use for helpdesk issues in an extremely busy area. I've tried various ways to get text into the field and scoured the internet looking for the correct way to do it, however either I'm searching for the wrong keywords or I'm blind.

the specific field I'm trying to manipulate is below:

**input name="custom_ticket_form_field_2" type="text" style="width: 400px" value=""**

The area I'm having trouble with:

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim objIE : Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
 objIE.Visible = true
 objIE.Navigate "http://xxxx/xxxx"
 Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
 WScript.Sleep 500
 Loop 

 objIE.Document.getElementsBy**????**("custom_ticket_form_field_2").value = "laptop"
```

No matter how I try to identify(????) the "custon_ticket_form_field_2" I can't seem to get the text to end up there. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByName("custom_ticket_form_field_2").item(0).value
```

Comment: Still getting "object does not support this action" error as before with the above.

Comment: Post the actual code you're using, there is not enough information here to help you debug your problem. The code snippet I provided is valid syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you need here, sorry. I can literally run just that portion of the code as is and it fails on the line in question.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, newbie and all.